# Failure to sync ExtJS store with Yii model on server: 400 Bad Request (POST)

Tags: php, ajax, extjs, yii, csrf

I want to sync my ExtJS store with Yii models on server. The reading goes smooth, but the writing to the server is not smooth: **400 Bad request** (POST).

 The response goes: **"You are not authorized to perform this request."** 
The data are indeed formed in the POST: 

**Form Data** 
records:{"article":"YD40516","oem":"3397004667","title":"\u0429\u0435\u0442\u043a ...

In the store constructor:

```
this.proxy =         
        {   
            url:  "index.php?r=backend/index&Table=" + this.modelName + this.params,
            reader: { 
                 root: "data",
                 totalProperty: "count",     
                 type: "json"
            }, 
            writer: { 
                 root: "records",                    
                 encode: true,
                 writeAllFields : false,   
                //type: "json"
            },
            type:"ajax",
            // limitParam: this.limitParam,
        };
```

I've followed [this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/609/default-csrf-security-and-ajax-post-in-one-controller/) on how to add `csrfToken` to my POST ajax requests, yet it brought no result.
Still **400 Bad request**, no `Yii_CSRF_TOKEN` post parameter added, though in the source-html there is this insertion:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     data: {"YII_CSRF_TOKEN": "63f62ed9c92752fab910386195d84eb8b0bbd420"},
     cache:false
 });
```

I've tried to add method redefinig to the proxy config but useless:

```
actionMethods: {
   read: 'GET', write: 'GET'
},
```

still for writing it goes POST without Yii_CSRF_TOKEN

Any help, any direction?

Answer (score 0):

i've done it with setting extra parameter in store proxy:

```
this.proxy =         
        {  
            url:  "index.php?r=backend/index&Table=" + this.modelName + this.params,
            reader: { 
                ...
            }, 
            actionMethods: {
                  read: 'GET', update: 'POST'
            }, 
            extraParams: {YII_CSRF_TOKEN : CSRF_TOKEN },  
            writer: { 
                 root: "records",                    
                 encode: true,    
                 type: "json"
            },
            type:"ajax", 
        };
```

but the trick was to insert `CSRF_TOKEN` as js variable.
So i used the layout file to manually insert `CSRF_TOKEN` in html BEFORE registered ExtJS js files:
In layout file i've inserted:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>         
     var CSRF_TOKEN = '" . Yii::app()->request->getCsrfToken() . "'; 
     console.log('CSRF_TOKEN = '+ CSRF_TOKEN);
</script>";
```

In a view file the js script pertaining to the store:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile("js/UniversalStore.js"); ?>
```